# Avoid Express API Timeout, for a service that takes a lot of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, timeout, axios

I have an api that uses express and it generates android applications for users, it takes on average 40-50 seconds to make an app and respond to the frontend request, but my requests always timeout before that.

```
const { data } = await axios.post(`http://apiexample.com/${id}`, {}, {timeout: 1000000})
```

I added the timeout option to my frontend

```
function (req, res) {
  req.setTimeout(0)
  ......
}
```

and this is my express callback on the backend.
Am I missing something here? or is there a better way to avoid my timeout problem that I should be using?

Comment: Polling . . . . .

Comment: ...or web sockets

Comment: @VtoCorleone Thanks, I didn't know about web sockets and they seem like a good solution.